# Problems about import

Tags: python, import

The following is structure of my program

./abc.py

./a/__init__.py

./b/__init__.py

./b/t.py

Source code of abc.py

```
import a
```

Source code of ./a/__init__.py

```
from b import t
```

Source of of ./b/t.py

```
def aa():
   print "bbb"
```

./b/__init__.py is an empty file.

There is a statement

```
t.aa()
```

if I put it into ./a/__init__.py, then when I run abc.py, it works fine.
But if I put it into abc.py, when I run the script, I get an error like

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "abc.py", line 3, in 
>      t.aa()
>   NameError: name 't' is not defined

What's the reason of this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

t has been imported into a, and is thus available to code w/in a.  And while a has been imported into abc, what a imports has not.